# 干 / 做 / 作 / 办/ 弄/ 搞 / what are the differences and how are they properly used in a sentence?

Tags: difference, word

For the first four sentences I think these words are interchangeable, except for the second sentences i think ^^

小明在家里（ ）作业。（做 作 弄 ）

我刚（ ）好了一个手艺品。（做 搞 ）

我要把这件事（ ）明白。（弄 搞 办 干）

你事情（ ）好了吗？（办 弄 做 搞 干 作 ）

假期（ ）喜欢（ ）的事。（做 作 干 搞 弄 办）

我喜欢学习汉语，以后（  ）什么还没想好。（做 作 干 办 搞 弄）

Answer (score 2):

Each of the six characters 办 弄 做 搞 干 作 has more than one meaning and usage. And some are overlapping e.g. both 做 and 干 contains the meaning of 'to do'

> 你事情（ ）好了吗？（办 弄 做 搞 干 作 ）

The role of the verb in ( ) is to bond with the adverb 好 to form a [serial verb] that means [complete/ finish]

*好 here as an adverb means 'completely; properly'*

- 办好 - complete/ finish (through following a series of procedures)
- 弄好 - complete/ finish (through manipulating)
- 做好 - complete/ finish (through actions)
- 搞好 - same as 弄好 (but more colloquial)
- 干好 - same as 做好 (but more colloquisl)

*作好 would mean 'finished creating/writing a story' It would be a simple [v + adv] phrase, not a serial verb like the other*

As for the overlapping meaning of 'to do'

办大事 = do important things (through following a series of procedures)

做大事 = do important things (through actions)

干大事 same as 做大事 (but more colloquial)

We don't say 弄大事 (sound small) or 搞大事 (means making trouble) for this context

- 弄 in 弄晚餐 (make dinner) means 'make' not 'do'
- 搞 in 搞聚會 (organize party) means 'organize' not 'do'

Comment: 弄疼我了。why here used 弄 not 搞？   搞钱=弄钱？

Comment: 搞疼我了 sounds like you are rude while having sex and your girlfriend complains that you hurt her。

Answer (score 0):

小明在家里（ ）作业。（做 作 弄 ） - **做**

我刚（ ）好了一个手艺品。（做 搞 ） - **做**. 搞, rarely in use.

我要把这件事（ ）明白。（弄 搞 办 干） - **弄, 搞**

你事情（ ）好了吗？（办 弄 做 搞 干 作 ） - **办, 做, 搞**. 干, rarely in use.

假期（ ）喜欢（ ）的事。（做 作 干 搞 弄 办） - **做,作. 干,干. 搞,弄. 弄搞**

我喜欢学习汉语，以后（ ）什么还没想好。（做 作 干 办 搞 弄）- **作**

Note that 做,作 are synonyms with different uses (similar to big & large). **做** is usually used to refer to something specific which you can see or touch (tangible) such as 做事, 做衣服, and 做作业, while **作** is to describe something abstract or intangible like 作孽, 作弊, 作曲, and 作业.

Comment: When do you use 搞 instead of 弄. Is there any specific use or are they interchangeable?

Comment: Yes, in most cases they are interchangeable but with a few exceptions that associated with idioms -  弄璋弄瓦, 弄巧成拙 造化弄人. Other than these, use 搞 instead of 弄 will be more likely to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

小明在家里（做 ）作业。（做 作 弄 ）

我刚（ 做 ）好了一个手艺品。（做 搞 ）

我要把这件事（ 弄 搞）明白。（弄 搞 办 干）

你事情（办 弄 做 搞 干 ）好了吗？（办 弄 做 搞 干 作 ）搞 干are usually less formal

假期（做  干 ）喜欢（做 干  ）的事。（做 作 干 搞 弄 办）

我喜欢学习汉语，以后（做 干 ）什么还没想好。（做 作 干 办 搞 弄）